# How to know if the code should be interpreted into HTML attributes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the Angular UI Bootstrap Popover component.
I wrote a small javascript expression to evaluate the `placement` of the popover but apparently my code is not evaluated.

Can somebody explain why (The sample of code below)?

```
<div ng-repeat="User in Users track by $index" popover-placement="{[0,1,5].indexOf($index) === -1 ? 'top' : 'bottom'}" popover="TEST">
  <!-- SOME CODE -->
</div>
```

The popover always appear at the top position on the 6 items (user), which is the default behavior.

Comment: You are right i thought {} was to evaluate and {{}} to output datas... Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `{{}}`, to evaluate an expression. All you are giving it now is an incomplete object.

```
<div ng-repeat="User in Users track by $index" popover-placement="{{[0,1,5].indexOf($index) === -1 ? 'top' : 'bottom'}}" popover="TEST">
  <!-- SOME CODE -->
</div>
```